# different between android 5.0.2 and 5.0.1

Tags: java, android

I just want to know what is diffrent between android 5.0.1 and 5.0.2 .
because  my application works perfect in 5.0.2 but i have problem in android 5.0.1.

look here in my code I put if clause to check the version of device, but It cant recognize the 5.0.2 from 5.0.1.

```
 public static Bitmap downSampleBitmap(Uri uri, Activity act, Boolean needRotate) {
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    Resources r = act.getResources();
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            50, r.getDisplayMetrics()); // 50: magic num
    int targetWidth = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int targetHeight = displaymetrics.widthPixels - px;

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = decodeSampledBitmap(uri, targetWidth, targetHeight, act);
    Bitmap returnBitmap = null;
    ExifInterface exif;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP  && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(uri.toString());
            int orient = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            rotateBitmap(returnBitmap,orient);
            returnBitmap = returnBitmap == null ? resizedBitmap : returnBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "not found file at downsample");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        try {
            float degree = 0;
            exif = new ExifInterface(uri.toString());
            int orient = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            if (resizedBitmap != null && needRotate) {
                degree = getDegree(orient);
                if (degree != 0) {
                    returnBitmap = createRotatedBitmap(resizedBitmap, degree);
                }
                returnBitmap = returnBitmap == null ? resizedBitmap : returnBitmap;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "not found file at downsample");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return returnBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Athough they have same name "LOLLIPOP" but i got two different reaction

Comment: what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: yes, it will help if you describe what the problem is......

Comment: My imageview rotated when I capture pics.In 5.0.2 it was ok but in 5.0.1 it wasnt ok and rotate it . I use this code to rotate in 5.0.1 and now It was ok but in 5.02 no

Comment: first of all, your if clause could not be true if you test this on LOLLIPOP. You say: `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP&& Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` . But if you test on LOLLIPOP, it doesn´t matter which LOLLIPOP, because the version is NOT SMALLER. So the second one will not be checked by the if clause and the else block will be executed. Instead, check it with `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){}`only....

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: see my comment above....then it will  execute the if statement if the version is lower or equal to lollipop....

Comment: yes Know what you said , if i just check if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){} in android 5.0.2 dont work perfect

Comment: `new ExifInterface(uri.toString())` will not work reliably on any version of Android, because `uri.toString()` is not going to always be something that `ExifInterface` can use. In fact, if this works on *any* version of Android, it is dumb luck. Please [use `Uri` values properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html), and [use an EXIF library that handles arbitrary sources of images](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/31/tale-two-exifinterfaces.html).